# three.js create a mesh from a gltf objections

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality

I have rendered a gltf object in three.js, but the issue is I don't think it contains a mesh. I want to use a ray caster to move the object with an on click event handler. I have all the code in place to do this, but it doesn't register when I click.

Code to load the object:

```
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
    // resource URL
    './vitra_eames_plastic_chair/scene.gltf',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {

        object.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        object.scene; // THREE.Scene
        object.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
        object.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        object.asset; // Object

        var object = new THREE.Mesh(gltf.asset, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
        object.scene.position.x = -75;
        object.scene.position.y = -75;
        object.scene.position.z = -75;
        object.scene.rotation.x = 50;
        object.scene.rotation.y = 50;
        object.scene.rotation.z = 50;
        object.scene.scale.x = .5;
        object.scene.scale.y = .5;
        object.scene.scale.z = .5;
        object.scene.castShadow = true;
        object.scene.receiveShadow = true;
        boxScene.add(object.scene);
        objects.push(object.scene);
    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

    }
);
```

I also have this code, which generates boxes. Here, the event handler works, but obviously the object were loaded differently. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
    object.position.x = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
    object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    object.scale.x = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
    object.scale.y = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
    object.scale.z = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
    object.castShadow = true;
    object.receiveShadow = true;
    boxScene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
}
```

Comment: _"I don't think it contains a mesh"_ It contains a mesh/meshes. Could you provide the code for your raycaster and how you try to get intersection?

Comment: If it renders it contains a mesh.

Comment: @prisoner849 `var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change your `onLoad()` callback of `GLTFLoader.load()` to fix the problem. You are creating a mesh with `object.asset` which is not correct. Instead, you can add `object.scene` directly to your scene graph. So in most cases the callback can simply be like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( function( gltf ) {

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

) };
```

Check out the source code of the following example to see this approach in action.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html

Comment: What if you need to change the material of it dynamically ? i need to change the texture to a video, Just like the video example in your site @Mugen87